# Outlook - Missing 'Disable Always Move Conversation' option in Shared Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

There is actually some `Always Move Conversations` options which were created in a shared mailbox, but since this `Always Move Conversations` thing is not a rule, the only way to get rid of it, AFAIK, is to use the `Disabled Always Move Conversation` in the 'Move' menu. Unfortunately, this option is missing, so we can't stop the redirection of the emails!

I know about the command `Outlook.exe /cleanconvongoingactions`, but we don't want to remove ALL of the `Moves`, but only 1.

Anyone knows as to why this option is missing? Could it be because it is in a Shared Mailbox used by multiple people or something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `Always Move Conversations` option is NOT available in a shared mailbox at all.**

We found out that it was instead a rule which was moving the mails, but it was not available in the Outlook client, but only on the web by searching in the shared mailbox rules.